# Is it upgrade safe to add custom address attributes

Tags: attributes, database, upgrade

currently, I am developing a Magento extension, that needs to add several custom attributes to the customer address.
I've found several tutorials on the topic that describe precisely what I need to build
http://www.unexpectedit.com/magento/add-new-customer-attribute-onepage-magento-checkout
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address

They all use ALTER TABLE to add columns to several DB tables. My question is :

Is it upgrade safely to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is upgrade proof, the whole idea of the EAV model is that you can safely add attributes without having problem with upgrades etc. For the customer section there only isn't an interface to add customer attributes like there is for products (there is on the EE edition). Because of this you need to run the scripts as described in those blogposts.

Comment: @EvgeniIvanov - Paul is correct here, but I would like to point out (since he did not) that when you add an attribute to an EAV model, ALTER TABLE queries are not used since columns are not being added. Since customer and customer address models are EAV, it's merely adding the needed records to the eav_* tables to define the attribute.

Comment: I just need one last clarification: i need to alter the "sales_flat_order_address" and "sales_flat_quote_address" table.Since those two table are "flat" is this OK.

Comment: Yes, this is no problem.